# Why TabView and MapView didn't work together?

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I have a simple tabView, with 2 tabs. In first tab i show some listview, in second i wanna show map. But when i try to is my app is broke.

There is my tabview code:

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Resources res = getResources();

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        Intent i = getIntent();

        Intent intentList = new Intent().setClass(this, ListActivity.class);
        intentList.putExtra(StartActivity.SEARCH_KEY, i.getStringExtra(StartActivity.SEARCH_KEY));
        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpecList = tabHost.newTabSpec("List").setContent(intentList).setIndicator(res.getString(R.string.list_tab));

        Intent intentMap = new Intent().setClass(this, MapPlaceActivity.class);
        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpecMap = tabHost.newTabSpec("Map").setContent(intentMap).setIndicator(res.getString(R.string.map_tab));

        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecList);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecMap);
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }

}
```

When i run app i have that's error:

```
07-27 14:12:23.676: ERROR/dalvikvm(19527): Could not find class 'com.example.MapPlaceActivity', referenced from method com.example.MainActivity.onCreate
07-27 14:12:23.676: WARN/dalvikvm(19527): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 66 (Lcom/example/MapPlaceActivity;) in Lcom/example/MainActivity;
07-27 14:12:23.686: WARN/dalvikvm(19527): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
07-27 14:12:23.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19527): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.MapPlaceActivity
        at com.example.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

But i realy have MapPlaceActivity, there is code from it:

```
public class MapPlaceActivity extends MapActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

And there is my layout file(map.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="Hiden key"
/>
```

My Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name">

        <activity android:name=".StartActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Pref"
                  android:label="@string/settings_label"
                  >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MapPlaceActivity"
                  android:label="@string/map_tab"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ListActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/> should be added inside the   <application>....</application>

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to add the uses library line inside the application tag in the manifest file.

Also you can give the following tags if you wish

```
<supports-screens
android:anyDensity="true"
android:resizeable="true"
android:largeScreens="true" />
```